# Paytm integration in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have created Web Application for Real estate doamin in NodeJS and now want to implement Paytm integration with my web app. I really don't getting any document from paytm or not any blog.

I found many answers reagrding integration with ios, android but i am not able to get any thing with node.js.

My Requirements is i want to implement paytm walllet from which customer can transfer creadit from his wallet to merchant's wallet.

Is Paytm provide any web api ? Can anyone please help me out on it.

Comment: Have you purchase merchant account for payment ?

Comment: No @Hiren. can you suggest way. how can i make it done. i just want to integrate wallet. i don't wan't to be a seller. i don't know what type of account i need to create to do this. can you please assist me.

Comment: As you said, "My Requirements is i want to implement paytm walllet from which customer can transfer creadit from his wallet to merchant's wallet." So here what is the merchant's wallet

Comment: Got your point @hiren, I have just created mechant account in paytm and looking into it.

Comment: @hiren: do you know, is paytm provides sandbox type of account ? right now it don't allow me to test without filling bank information.

Answer (score 0):

There are two api's you can write.
1. Pay api 
2. Response api

Firstly, You have to generate checksum [link](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_NodeJs) (clone and use in paytm file for generating checksum) using customers information and paytm keys, redirect that data into html which is provided [here](http://%20https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/payment-gateway)

store response by adding you update customer api into callback url

Comment: Do you know how we can do it if react js is frontend and node is backend . Since axios doesn't redirect to nodejs to Paytm page